# How to concatenate two string values on the same line?

Tags: python, bash, concatenation, weblogic, wlst

I'm writing two scripts, the first in bash and the second one in Python. The desired output is an IP address and the port number on the same line without spaces like

- ip:port

Here's the bash:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo $(find /u01/ -name config.xml |grep -v bak| xargs grep -A4 AdminServer | grep listen-address | cut -d'>' -f 2 | cut -d'<' -f 1)
```

and its output

```
172.31.138.15
```

The Python:

```
import os
import sys
from java.lang import System
import getopt
import time

values = os.popen(str('sh /home/oracle/scripts/wls/adminurl.sh'))
url = str("".join(map(str, values)))
port = ":7001"
adminurl = url + port + "\n"

def connectToDomain():
    try:
        if ServerName != "" or username == "" and password == "" and adminUrl == "":
            print (adminurl)
            connect(userConfigFile='/home/oracle/scripts/wls/userconfig.secure', userKeyFile='/home/oracle/scripts/wls/userkey.secure', url=adminurl, timeout=60000)

[...]
```

and its output

```
Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

172.31.138.15
:7001

Connecting to t3://172.31.138.15
:7001
 with userid weblogic ...
This Exception occurred at Fri Jan 10 18:00:22 CET 2020.
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: 172.31.138.15
: unknown error [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: 172.31.138.15
: unknown error]

The domain is unreacheable
```

I need the ip value on the same line as the port value so that '**adminurl**' is recognized as an argument within the '**connect**' function.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `echo` and don't add a newline. Then just run them in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adminurl = url.rstrip() + port + "\n"

Comment: When you read the value from the file it contains a newline character appended to the end of it. The .rstrip() on the url will remove that newline.